# which web framework for small web-app

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, web-frameworks

maybe you guys can help me i have a little problem here:

I have Embedded Devices connected to the Internet. They are permanently logging data to files. These files are sent to my webserver. 
They have about 10k lines and each line looks like: (timestamp;data). the data-block contains 8byte equals 64 ON/OFF values ..

Now i want to create a web-app that allows me to:

-Administrate/Control the Embedded Devices (opening ssh connection and send commands)

-Visualize the logfiles on a timeline (i want to visualize these values e.g. by a green/red LED grouped by the timestamp where i can scroll and speed up)

So the technical requirements from my POV:

- user authentication
- javascript integration for visualizing logfiles
- orm mapper

I prefer python as programming language for the business logic, but i am not afraid to try something new.

And now the question that i am asking me is:
**What framework should i use?**

I mean i already had a look at django and web2py, but i think these frameworks are way to big for this little project.

Comment: This is a question of your own flavor. I would have a look at Ruby on Rails... since I prefer it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small webapps in Python, I usually use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Since you seem to do raw data processing, I would refrain from using an ORM and just use SQLAlchemy to query the values directly (although SQLAlchemy comes with an ORM if you insist on using one)

Comment: +1 on flask. Well designed, responsive community, excellently documented.

Comment: Flask is great, depending on your DB preferences, you might also be interested in looking into MongoDB for the database, great for working with log style data.

Comment: MongoDB is best suited for unstructured data such as arbitrary log message strings. Since he has a well defined type of log message (basically key->value pairs with an order on the keys) it is exactly what traditional RDMS are optimized for.

Comment: thanks for you reply. that helped me a lot: i just want do add that i don't wanna save the logfile analysis in a db, because i already have the "raw file". i just need to visualize these raw logfiles

the logfile actually looks like n tuples of (timestamp;identifier;data)
depending on the identifier each data-byte can have a different datatype(worst case 64bool values). this is all defined in the "identifier-template"

based on the identifier template i create an in-memory db table where i have fast access to the data and do all filtering, grouping,..

what do you think of this approach?

Comment: @user1320852 sounds good, although I would cache as much of the processing results as possible. You might also want to have a look at RRDTool for inspiration ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) on Ruby is probably what you are looking for.

On the persistence level, I would use MongoDB. Here's the [quick start](http://www.garrensmith.com/2010/09/11/Mongoid-sinatra.html).

As far as security goes, there are tons of options, here's [sinatra security](https://github.com/sinefunc/sinatra-security).

OAuth would also be a good choice, so here's a link to use [Gmail's auth](https://github.com/nfo/gmail-oauth-sinatra) with some Strawberry cream.

Comment: I would advise against MongoDB, since pairs of a timestamp + a well defined and fixed value type is exactly what RDMS handle very well...

Comment: @mensi why? Why is RDMS best for that?

Comment: @Raynos because it is exactly that: relational data of a fixed schema. This is kind of the job description of a relational database. If you are concerned about the overhead of transactional semantics, you can always use MySQL with MyISAM or something similar. MongoDB is a document/object database, meaning untyped, generic datablobs.

Comment: @Raynos insulting me is not going to make your point more valid. Another thing to consider: MongoDB will be very wasteful in storing this single number for every timestamp, since it will allocate more space than necessary to be able to handle dynamic content (I believe MongoDB's implementation is to allocate twice the size). An RDMS will only allocate the exact number of bytes needed for an entry.

Comment: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging

Comment: IT doesnt really matter either way, they both work.

Comment: @MattEsch the only interesting part of this article that would apply here are capped collections, but there is a better tool for this in this case: [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having good experiences using http://webpy.org/ for small apps. It's more of a anti-framework than a framework per se. A minimalist approach to web development.

Here's the quote that best defines it to me:

> "Django lets you write web apps in Django. TurboGears lets you write web apps in TurboGears. Web.py lets you write web apps in Python."
>     —  Adam Atlas

And as @mensi said, I would use SQLAlchemy for the ORM mapper

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).  Super simple.  However, it is single-threaded out-of-the-box, meaning multiple users are not well-supported.  [Cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/) is multi-threaded and a bit more cumbersome.